# Async await throws an error I don't understand how to fix?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a piece an exiting piece of code that calls stored procedures in a database.  This looks like this

```
var tasks = relayRequests.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    () => x.Service.ProcessMessage(x.Message, relayTimeoutSeconds)
                    ));
var result = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Now I have to enhance this code where it calls an additonal web service. This web service is `async`. To do this I added this code

```
Task t = new Task(async () => await CallClassService());
```

and I changed

```
var result = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

to

```
var result = Task.WhenAll(tasks,t);
```

Now the problem is that I am getting this compiler error that I don't understand how to fix.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Personally i think the powers that be should remove code formatting back-ticks

Comment: Is `ProcessMessage` async ? Should it be ?

Comment: `Task t = new Task( async () => await CallClassService());` have you instead considered `var t = CallClassService()`;?

Comment: Does `var result = Task.WhenAll(tasks.Append(t));` work? _As a hint - whenever you get an error be sure to **read the docs** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__ ._

Comment: You should neither use `Task.Factory.StartNew` nor `new Task` – aside from very special cases always use `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `await` the `Task`. Remembering `Task.WhenAll` returns a `Task`

```
var tasks = relayRequests.Select(x => 
      Task.Run(
          () => x.Service.ProcessMessage(x.Message, relayTimeoutSeconds)));

var result = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Also there is no need to *offload* an `async` call  to the *threadpool* unless there is a compelling case to do so

```
Task t = new Task( async () => await CallClassService());
```

should just be

```
Task t = CallClassService();
```

or

```
await CallClassService();
```

---

As pointed out in a worthy comment by [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills)

The definitions for `WhenAll` are follows

- `WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task>)`

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the Task objects in an
> enumerable collection have completed.

- `WhenAll(Task[])`

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the Task objects in an
> array have completed.

- `WhenAll<TResult>(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>)`

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the Task
> objects in an enumerable collection have completed.

- `WhenAll<TResult>(Task<TResult>[])`

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the Task
> objects in an array have completed.

None of which can take a mixture of a collection and a task. i.e `Task.WhenAll(tasks,t);`

You will need to combine them

```
Task.WhenAll(tasks.Append(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the definition of `Task.WhenAll. Which overload do you want to use, and what parameters do you supply?

But let's first take a look at another problem.

`tasks` is an `IEnumerable`, it has not be enumerated yet, the tasks are not started yet. Only after someone enumerates over the sequence (foreach and similar), the tasks are started.

If you enumerate over them, and later enumerate again, you will start the tasks again. So my advice would be, to use a `ToList`, so all tasks are started, before you decide to `WhenAll`:

```
List<Task> tasks = ...
           .ToList();
```

Now you are certain, that if you or someone else enumerates over tasks, `Task.Factory.StartNew` is not called again.

Apparently you want to start these tasks, and you want to start an extra task `t`. Then you want to wait until all tasks are finished.

All [overloads of Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1) take either an array of Tasks, or an `IEnumerable<Task>`. Your code, without the `var` is:

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = ...
Task t = ...
var result = Task.WhenAll(tasks,t);
```

Simple: there is no overload that takes an `IEnumerable<Task>, Task`.

The simple solution:

```
Task[] tasks = relayRequests.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(
                () => x.Service.ProcessMessage(x.Message, relayTimeoutSeconds)))
    .Concat(new Task[] {CallClassService()})
    .ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

But maybe you like the following solution.

Apparently you have a class with a method ProcessMessage. You would have liked a method `ProcessMessageAsync`.

```
class Service
{
    public void ProcessMessage(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) {...}
    public async Task ProcessMessageAsync(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) {...}
}
```

Note: if ProcessMessage returns TResult, then ProcessMessageAsync should return `Task<TResult>`. I don't know the parameters of your ProcessMessage, but you get the gist.

If you can't change this class, consider creating an extension method. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

public static ProcessMessageAsync(this Service service,
Message message,
TimeSpan timeout)
{
// start a task that calls Service.ProcessMessage:
return Task.Run(() => service.ProcessMessage(message, timeout);
}

So the sync version:

```
Service service = ...
Message message = ...
TimeSpan timeout = ...

service.ProcessMessage(message, timeout);
```

Because of the extension method, the async version would be:

```
await service.ProcessMessageAsync(message, timeout);
```

Now that you've got the extension method, your code would look way more neater:

```
async Task ProcessRelayRequestsAsync(IEnumerable<RelayRequests>relayRequests)
{
    Timeout timeout = ...
    List<Task> startedTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var relayRequest in relayRequests)
    {
        Task startedTask = service.ProcessMessageAsync(relayRequest.Message, timeout);
        startedTasks.Add(startedTask);
    }
    startedTasks.Add(callClassService());

    // now that all Tasks are started; await for them to complete:
    await Task.WhenAll(startedTasks);

    // if any of the tasks have a result, you can process them now.
}
```

If your ProcessRelayRequests is not async:

```
void ProcessRelayRequests(IEnumerable<RelayRequests>relayRequests)
{
    Timeout timeout = ...
    List<Task> startedTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var relayRequest in relayRequests)
    {
        Task startedTask = service.ProcessMessageAsync(relayRequest.Message, timeout);
        startedTasks.Add(startedTask);
    }
    startedTasks.Add(callClassService());
    Task.WaitAll(startedTasks);
}
```

The difference is in `Task.WaitAll`, instead of the `Task.WhenAll`